# Why does JavaRDD count() return different result?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

A JavaRDD object of type [SimpleFeature](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/feature/simple/SimpleFeature.html) is created. Then I call the method count of the same object three times in a row and I get different results. I don't understand why, since the object does not change (I don't apply any transformation on it). The following code is the part of code involved:

```
public static final boolean S = true;
public static final boolean D = false;
public static final boolean C = true;

//...class envelope

//...static method
//...some code
JavaRDD<SimpleFeature> myRdd = //...inizialize RDD
if(C) {
   logger.info(myRdd.count()); // this line prints 79
}
if(!D || S) {
   logger.info(myRdd.count()); // this line prints 60
   method(myRdd, ...); // this method does not change RDD, it just stores each record in a DB
   logger.info(myRdd.count()); // this line prints 63
}
//...some code

//...end of class envelope
```

As you can see in the comments of the code above, the logger.info prints out a different number each time (at first 79, then 60 and eventually 63), although I don't modify myRdd object (I don't do neither a single map between the two if blocks). Could you please explain to me why it happens?

Comment: You should include the actions that initialize your RDD.

Comment: Most probably you have some randomness during creation of rdd. In spark all transformations (including creation of rdd) are lazy. It means each `count` is applied to different rdd.